# Quickest way to tell if two lists are complements of each other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, xor

I have two arrays:

```
a = [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
b = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
```

What is the fastest way to determine if each element is the inverse of the other (the complement)?

So to make it obvious the above would return `True`

but for these arrays:

```
a = [1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
b = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
```

it would return `False`

I think this question is very clear but for more details:

- By "fastest" I mean fastest in terms of speed (in seconds)
- The arrays are not limited to a length of eight, but the number of elements in the arrays will be the same
- The elements will always be either `0` or `1`
- I expect an even number of non-complement and complement arrays

Comment: Are the array values just one or zero?

Comment: Fastest with respect to what? A fixed size? Some n? Is there some bound on your data? Do they always start as lists or can you read them in differently, say an integer literal or bytes? Do you primarily expect complement or non-complement sequences?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I believe that I updated the question to answer your questions.  I see here that you posted some reasons why other methods are not ideal - do you have any suggestions as to solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2**

If the numbers *are only 1 or 0*, you can test for complement by simply comparing them. This is about 15% faster than testing the sum:

```
complement = all(False for aa , bb in zip(a, b) if aa == bb)
```

**Update**

Based on comments, I did some time testing. It is indeed faster (by about 20%) to filter the list before testing it with `all` i.e.

```
complement = all(False for aa, bb in zip(a, b) if aa ^ bb != 1)
```

What is weird is that:

```
complement = all(False for va, vb in zip(a, b) if va + vb != 1)
```

is faster again, by about 10%. This doesn't make any sense to me, as addition is a far more complicated operation than bitwise xor.

**Original answer**

You can use bitwise `xor` to determine if the values are complements.

```
a = [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
b = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]

complement = all(aa ^ bb == 1 for aa , bb in zip(a, b))
print(complement)
# True

a = [1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
b = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]

complement = all(aa ^ bb == 1 for aa , bb in zip(a, b))
print(complement)
# False
```

This can also be made to work if they are values other than `0` or `1` by comparing with `2^n-1` where `n` is the bit-length of the values:

```
a = [3, 2, 1, 0]
b = [0, 1, 2, 3]

complement = all(aa ^ bb == 3 for aa , bb in zip(a, b))
print(complement)
# True
```

Comment: Note that this is not the fastest. It will do many unnecessary context switches from the generator to all on each True.

Comment: @RoadRunner Because I don't think the question should be answered in this state. Either way, an expression of the form ``all(a for a in b)`` is generally slower than ``all(False for a in b if not a)``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm interested to know why that is?

Comment: Now your definitely going to confuse your coworkers with that *faster* solution. The 20% gain doesn't seem worth it IMO.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I added some timing info to my answer, proving your assertion correct, but also with some (to me) strange results, in that addition is faster than bitwise xor. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @RoadRunner I just wanted to see if it was indeed faster and thought I would share the results.

Comment: @Nick I would assume the problem with ``+`` versus ``^`` are Python's arbitrary precision ``int``s, which CPython cannot optimise well. ``1`` uses a 32bit content block, ``0`` does not; depending on how these are optimised, CPython might have to use the full "different content size" logic. I would not rule out that there is a fast path for ``a + 0`` but not for ``a ^ 0``, either. This probably looks different on PyPy, where both ``1`` and ``0`` are equally sized tagged pointers.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I guess that could make sense. Gives some ideas for improvement...

Answer (score 7):

You can zip the lists to compare the pairs. In order to know if they 'complement' each other, as all of your values are 1 or 0, just check if their sum is 1:

```
a = [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
b = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]

all(va + vb == 1 for va, vb in zip(a, b))
# True

a = [1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
b = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]

all(va + vb == 1 for va, vb in zip(a, b))
# False
```

Note that using `all` with a generator expression will only check what is necessary to decide, it will stop as soon as a pair that isn't valid is encountered.

Comment: Note that this is not the fastest. It will do many unnecessary context switches from the generator to all on each True.

Answer (score 1):

Can use [`operator.xor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.xor) to do bitwise XOR along with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to zip the two lists together and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to check if all the pairs are complements or return `1`:

```
>>> import operator
>>> a = [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
>>> b = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
>>> all(operator.xor(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b))
True
>>> a = [1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
>>> b = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
>>> all(operator.xor(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b))
False
```

Comment: This is most certainly not the fastest. It will lookup ``operator.xor`` on each iteration step.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple for loop:

```
def is_complement(a, b):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] == b[i]:
            return False
    return True
```